# How to customize marker/symbol properties in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

Example command:

```
prop = matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(x,y,s=s,c=c)
```

`dir(prop)` shows set_edgecolor, set_edgecolors, set_linestyle, set_linestyles - why so many variations on the same thing?

Also, how do I remove the edgecolors? Setting values to `None` does nothing. And how do I change the marker size after the plotting? There does not appear to be a markersize attribute that I can access...

**Edit**

If the symbols are generated through `plyplot.plot`, there is a markersize attribute to change it seems. But with `pyplot.scatter`, not present.

Comment: FYI: A lot of the differences between `plot` and `scatter` have been fixed in the most recent version of matplotlib.  To remove the edge colors, set them to the string `'none'`.  In general in matplotlib, `None` means "use the default setting", whereas `'none'` means "no color".

Comment: Wow. The difference between None and 'none' is quite relevant! Thanks -- if you could put it as the answer I can mark it as solved...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd give using `'none'` a go to see if that solves your issue with edgecolor. That typically sets attributes to no color.